# Not Allowing to Create or Set BLOB/CLOB Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I have a large image around **200,000 length** in byte[].

whenever i try to **create an Object of BLOB/CLOB**

```
Blob blob = con.createBlob();
```

or

```
prepStmt.setBlob(1, is);
```

or **try to set it's value** like above it throws the following exception

**"java.lang.AbstractMethodError at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setBlob(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:388)"**

i tried to set it via

```
prepStmt.setBinaryStream(1,data,length);
```

it throws Exception as well because setBinaryStream() method can only store upto 3000 bytes of data Not more than that.

I googled and tried every possible solution.

1. Updated the JDBC and ODBC jars to latest
2. also tried this one `prepStmt.setObject(1, data, Types.BLOB);`

**What I have figured out is that application is not allowing me to instantiate or set BLOB/CLOB objects.**

**The OJDBC4.jar i am using and Oracle 11g database**

Anyone can help what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by upgrading the JDBC and ODBC jars and putting them in Tomcat lib folder